# Website only show directory listing on specific browsers

Tags: apache2, directory-listing

I have a website (https://hypermotions.com) which shows directory listing in some browsers only (such as iOS Chrome App), but most desktop & mobile browsers are able to display the website correctly.

What makes the Apache server having such behavior? The website is built using https://imcreator.com, but sure if it's related (thus I have no control on the files, such as `.htaccess`).

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the site apache config:

```
<Directory /var/www/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    ...........
    ..........
</Directory>
```

I hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't have the access to `.htaccess`, and it cannot explain why it's browser-specific.

Comment: The changes I am suggesting are to be done in the /etc/apache2/sites-xxxxxx not .htaccess.  The options listed enforce this behavior.  In addition, if your site configuration does not have a DirectoryIndex directive.  Some browsers will attempt to index the site instead of displaying it.

Comment: Understand. But it's hosted in IMCREATOR, therefore I have no control of any files.